# Magento2: Get gallery images in knockoutjs?

Tags: magento2, product-images, knockoutjs

How to get gallery images in knockoutjs in Magento2.3.0?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please add more details about this

Comment: I have customized my product variant images in frontend for multiple image upload, so while edit I need to get the gallery images. as the js is written in knockoutjs. So I am not able to get the gallery images. I am unaware of knockoutjs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass it to your component via the PHTML file, add this to your PHTML file:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".yourSelector": {
            "yourComponentAliasORPath": {
                "galleryImagesJson": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then in your JS you can access it with `this.config.galleryImagesJson`.

Comment: Hi, the link you shared are showing 404 error.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot those components haven't been open sourced yet, it works in the same way I mentioned above. You pass the data through to the JS within the `text/x-magento-init` tag and then in your JS you access it from this.config